# CakePHP 3.4 auth redirect

Tags: authentication, redirect, cakephp, cakephp-3.4

From version 3.4, CakePHP always adding redirect URL in query string, if action is not allowed for user.

It was described on https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/appendices/3-4-migration-guide.html#behavior-changes (3rd paragraph).

It is possible to remove redirect query string, and use in session, like before 3.4?

Comment: Why? You shouldn't for the many reasons outlined around the change :)

Comment: Hmm, because when i using friendly URL, the query string looks badly:)

Comment: It is a redirect URL designed for better user experience ;) it has nothing to do with friendly URLs, and also is irrelevant regarding the looks. Your session idea is broken by design, very very broken. If you understand it this way, there is clearly sth wrong here with your priorities.